# Google Spreadsheet API on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to add a row to an existing spreadsheet using list feed. But Every time I'm getting the following error "rror Domain=com.google.GDataServiceDomain Code=400 UserInfo=0xeddae4 "Operation could not be completed. (Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead.)"

I'm using the following code

```
GDataEntrySpreadsheetList *listEntry = [GDataEntrySpreadsheetList listEntry];
GDataSpreadsheetCustomElement *serialNo = [GDataSpreadsheetCustomElement elementWithName:@"SNo" stringValue:@"1"];
[array addObject:serialNo];
[[listEntry customElements] initWithArray:array];

//then after finding the worksheet
GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet *service = [self spreadsheetService];
NSURL *feedURL = [worksheet listFeedURL];
[service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:listEntry 
                            forFeedURL:feedURL 
                            delegate:self 
                            didFinishSelector:@selector(addTicket:addedEntry:error:)];
```

It seems i'm doing something wrong during the initialization of listEntry.

can some one help me on this or please provide me a sample code to insert a row into Google spreadsheet in Objective C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got my problem resolved  by calling the following method:

```
[listEntry setCustomElements:array];
```

instead of:

```
[[listEntry customElements] initWithArray:array];
```

Thanks,
Srinivas.M

Comment: hey buddy, your post also helped me.. thnx much :)